# Last logins during last hour

Tags: time, syslog, parrotsec, last, mx-linux

OK, so basically I'm trying to give a specific date and time and I want to see all the logins that were made during the hour range, e.g. last hour or two last hours from the time and date given. I need two ways as I don't have syslog everywhere, so basically on some systems last is somewhat working while on other - cat syslog.

This is what I've got so far

```
last | grep Dec | grep 1 | grep 17:*
```

and

```
cat syslog | grep Dec | grep 1 | grep 17:40 | grep -E ???
```

But it doesn't work. I mean it works and shows logins for a specific date and hour but nothing more. I cannot figure it out e.g. what to give after the -E parameter in order to get it going.

I checked similar threads but they didn't work for me either. In the ??? I tried putting many things with no success. Asterisk gave me some nice outcome, however this way you can only get full hours and if your range starts e.g. 16:40 then Houston, we've got a problem.

Comment: What about making a copy (via cron) of the wtmp file every hour and then use that copy for `last` (option `-f`)?

Comment: yeah I'm starting in Linux, so not everything is clear enough for me but as far as I've seen either I don't have wtmp or syslog on some systems. What it depends on? I initially thought that I had syslog because of the VmWare but then my collegue tried his linux on a vm and he still didn't have the syslog. I don't have it on a physical machine as well.

Comment: On my system `man last` says under "FILES": `/var/log/wtmp` (among others). Maybe today "syslog" is actually "journal" (systemd) (Try `journalctl -b`).

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect ?

```
LANG=C last | egrep "Fri\s*Dec\s*2 $(date '+%H')"
```

Comment: (december **2** on my side)

Comment: Not sure, I'm not getting any output when I'm writing that. It works however up to the date part.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you expect:

This gets the last logins during last hour:

```bash
last --since "$(date -d 'now - 1hour' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
```

And this shows logins from `25 Dec 2022` between `02:42` and `02:59`.

```bash
last --since '2022-12-25 02:42' --until '2022-12-25 02:59'
```

The hours are in **24-Hour Time Format**.  About `--until '2022-12-25 02:59'` the logins from `02:59` are ignored (I do not know why) so it will show only from `02:42` to `02:58` logins.

Also, if you want logins from specific user then use this:

```bash
last youruser --since '2022-12-25 02:42' --until '2022-12-25 02:58'
```